# Farming Hadium Flakes for Reforging the Blade

Tags: destiny

I am looking for this material so I can complete the "Reforging the Blade" quest. Is there a good place on the Dreadnought for farming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Video are very handy when it comes to material harvesting, as you can visually see the paths to take.

***EDIT***

I updated the answer to contain a brief summary of the route quoted in the video, in order to read the step-by-step process in the event the video is no longer valid.

1. As soon as you spawn, you will want to drop down to the left. There will be a little cavern underneath some piping, and a chest will spawn within.
2. After you exit the cavern, you will want to head towards the right side of the map, the side where the **hive** spawn. Towards the middle of that section of the map awaits another cavern where the 2nd chest will spawn.
3. Now when you exit the 2nd cavern, you will want to head towards the back wall of the side you are one. In that room will spawn the 3rd chest in this farming route, along with the chest that requires the **Key of Xol**.
4. For the fourth and final chest in this route, you will make a right
   after you exit the room with the 3rd chest. You will find a small cavern that contains a small passage way that leads into a mess of tunnels. I have noticed that the chest will spawn either within the room, or within the tunnels. It really depends where it decides to spawn.

I have sketched a rough drawing of the path to follow. This route makes farming *Hadium Flakes* fairly simple, but please note that the chests are not guaranteed to spawn every time.

[image]